# Create Personalized Controls For Java ME

Tags: java, controls, java-me, personalization

I'm starting to develop a eBook reader for mobile using Java ME, but for the control were the book will be shown I need a personalized control. For this I need to first know how to do one, to workaround with my needs.

Then I need to know how can I do a personalized control as we do with Visual Basic.

*PS: I want to do a personalized* `TextBox`*, that in some parts can be in bold, italic, sublined, that supports topics(as the Edit, the MS-DOS Text Editor) and many other things that make a eBook better viewed than a simple plain text*

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by personalized control and what they do? I'm not so familiar with Visual Basic's abilities. Or what particular aspect of this you're having difficulties with?

Comment: I want to create a personalized TextBox, that can highlight things, have bullets, italic, bold...

Answer (score 0):

In order to build custom components in JavaME with MIDP high level API you should extend [Custom Item](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html)

These two articles from Eric Giguere are a good starting point (a bit old, though):

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitem/
http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitemtraversal/index.html

Nevertheless, taking into account that your app is fairly complex and might require a richer and more flexible bunch of components, I would recommend [LWUIT](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/).

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/

(A fast and loose definition for LWUIT could be 'small Swing for JavaME')